# Generating a simple mathematical sequence in Python

Tags: python, functional-programming

I'm new to Python and coming from a PHP background.. I'm impressed.  Is there a way of getting a list of numbers from this sequence:

```
i^2, i^2 + i, i^2 + 2i, ..., n
```

i.e. if `i=2` and `n=30`:

`4, 6, 8, ..., 30`

Okay, this is a really simple sequence but is what's a more general way to do this sort of thing functionally?

Maybe there's some nice functional programming way of doing this?  In PHP I think I would make some function some variables and interaction but Python might be able to do it more elegantly?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with [range](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range):

```
In [186]: i = 2; n = 30; range(i**2, n+1, i)
Out[186]: [4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30]
```

Comment: @BlaXpirit: In Python2 it returns a list. In Python3 it returns an iterator.

Comment: That's not exactly true. But anyway, you should specify that you're using an outdated version of Python.

Comment: @unutbu: it's not an iterator but a [dedicated sequence type](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq), it supports subscription, for example.

Comment: @BlaXpirit: is Python 2 outdated?

Comment: The Python 2 series has finished at version 2.7. There will be an extended period of maintenance, but no version 2.8. The future is the Python 3 series, currently at version 3.3.

Answer (score 0):

Python has a cool feature called [List Comprehension](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/). You can use it to do something like this:

```
[i*i+2*n for n in range(30) if (i*i+2*n)<=30]
```